# How do I host a local lobby for a custom map (Arcade mode) in Dota 2, where Valve has enabled dedicated servers?

Tags: steam, dota-2, hosting

I keep getting disconnected from some custom maps in Dota 2 where Valve has dedicated servers enabled. One of the map creators said try doing a local server but I have no clue how I can do this in a custom map.

The maps I'm talking about have this indicator on them:
[image]

If I press "Create Custom Lobby" button, the arcade lobby system doesn't let me pick a server unlike the Dota 2 lobby system.

Normal custom lobby screen:[image]

Arcade custom lobby screen:[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've found out how to play the game as if it was a local lobby but not as an actual local lobby. So, basically you can host the game but only for yourself with this method and that's why I'm not going to choose this as the answer. The question is still how to do it as a locally hosted lobby and be able to play with friends.

Alright, on to the partial answer (click on pictures to see them bigger):

1. Find the ID of the mod map you want to play and don't forget to subscribe to the mod, in my case this was [302247405](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=302247405).

[image]

2. Get [Nem's Tools](http://nemesis.thewavelength.net/index.php?p=26) and install (choose vpk in the file associations if you don't want to bother later on) we'll need this in a few steps
3. Find the folder of your mods in steam, this will most likely be `Steam\steamapps\workshop\content\570\` for DotA2 and it was indeed that in my case. If you have multiple folders, the active folder should be wherever DotA is currently installed but you might have to look for it.
4. Find the folder with the ID of the custom map you wanted, this is the one we found at the start.

[image]

5. Open the ID.vpk with the tool we just downloaded. Something like this should be there.

[image]

6. Go to your DotA2 folder (you can go there by right clicking dota 2 in Steam going to properties > local files > browse local files) find the folder called dota_addons under game (on this path `dota 2 beta\game\dota_addons` but this might change later on as it is now there are four dota_addons folder and I had to try them one by one)
7. Make a new folder with a short name, something you'll be able to remember, I chose CHS because the mod is called Custom Hero Survival
8. Extract everything from the VPK to this folder, if everything went to plan you should now be in this position or something similar

[image]

9. Go into the game and go into the options menu and then advanced hotkeys, there should be something called `Console` set it something you don't normally use in game (otherwise it'll be a bother)

[image]

10. Press the hotkey to open the console and type in **"dota_launch_custom_game"** leave a space and type in the folder name you used for the mod and then the map name you want to play, in my case this was `dota_launch_custom_game chs hero_arena_coop` and your game should now load with no problems

Anyway, the issue of being unable to play with friends is still there, so this question will remain open until an answer with that detail comes.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a video about this,

Basically you just need to Forward the port (27015) and give your internet ip to the player who wanna Join, Wait in loading screen. Video can demonstrate it better, but i will wright down the steps.

Get the map id, open console (-console in launch parameters)

Type: dota_launch_custom_game (Map ID)

Port to Forward: 27015

After starting the map, Wait in loading screen give your internet ip to the player who wants to connect you, 
connect ip

Wait for him to join and when he join the game just select the slot and start.
Would recommend video cause it easier to understand from there.